# Change single patch color in geopandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, geopandas

Using [this map of NYC](http://www.nyc.gov/html/dcp/download/bytes/nybb_15b.zip) I'd like to change Manhattan to be bright blue.  But when I change the individual patch color of Manhattan all the other patch colors change too.  This was unexpected to me.

How do you change the color of one individual patch?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
nybb = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('nybb.shp')


nybb_plot = nybb.plot()
for p_ny in nybb_plot.patches:
    p_ny.set_color("#111111")
    p_ny.set_alpha(0.6)

for line in nybb_plot.lines:
    line.set_linewidth(0.25)
    line.set_alpha(0.9)
    line.set_color("#d3d3d3")

manhattan = nybb.loc[nybb.BoroName == "Manhattan"]

man_plot = manhattan.plot()
for p_mh in man_plot.patches:
    p_mh.set_color("#33ccff")

plt.show()
```

[image: Output figure of NYBB]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is using `geopandas.plotting.plot_multipolygon` to specifically add only one geometry object with blue colors to the existing figure:

```
from geopandas.plotting import plot_multipolygon
manhattan = nybb[nybb.BoroName == "Manhattan"]
plot_multipolygon(nybb_plot, manhattan.geometry.iloc[0], facecolor="#33ccff", edgecolor='none')
```

This gives me:

[image]

The reason your above approach does not work, is because geopandas adds the second plot to the same axes as the first plot (and this axes is returned from `plot()`). So `nybb_plot` and `man_plot` are referring to the same object, and so you do update all patches the second time.

---

Note that in the development version, the second plot will not automatically added anymore to the first, but a new figure will be created.

Comment: Thanks.  This works for me only if I remove the `edgecolor` argument.  Thoughts on how to solve this?

Comment: Ah, I was using the master (development) version. It seems this was not yet in the last released one. So options is upgrade to the master version (I think it is as stable as the last released one)

Comment: Other options is to just remove this, and set the edge colors (the color of the lines of the patches) to white just as you did in your question

Comment: Apparently plot_multipolygon does not exist in v 0.3.0 I just installed: ImportError: cannot import name plot_multipolygon. What is its replacement?