# GeoPandas plotting issues

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I am struggling with arguments when plotting with GeoPandas. For some reasons that I don't understand, I get this error

```
TypeError: plot_dataframe() got an unexpected keyword argument 'facecolor'
```

when trying to use 'facecolor', 'edgecolor',  'linewidth' and other arguments and keywords that are supposed to be passed to matplotlib (in my understanding).

Here an example of my code

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

my_shape=gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('myshape.shp')
f = plt.figure()
my_shape.plot(column='TYPE',colormap='cubehelix', alpha=0.5, categorical=True, legend=True, axes=f.gca(), edgecolor='w')
```

I might be doing something wrong but even when I try to reproduce this example :

[Change single patch color in geopandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465889/change-single-patch-color-in-geopandas)

I can't get it right and still get the type error

Thanks for your help

Python 2.7.10 Anaconda 2.0.1 (x86_64), Matplotlib 1.4.3, GeoPandas 0.1.1 (pysal 1.10.0, descartes 1.0.1)

Answer (score 1):

Other arguments and keywords like 'facecolor', 'edgecolor', 'linewidth' are **not** passed to matplotlib in version 0.1.1.
You can have a look in the docstring to see which arguments are supported.
In version 0.1.1 only colormap and alpha are supported keywords that style the plot.

In the current development version also `linewidth` is supported, *and* some color keywords are indeed passed to matplotlib.

Comment: Thanks Joris, my mistake I got GeoDataFrame and Pandas DataFrame mixed up in my understanding of GeoPandas. Thanks again